# What happened to my microsites in SFMC? Classic Content discontinued

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, cloudpage, content-builder, microsites

I used to have a very useful microsite, available only to logged-in users, which updated a query definition in Automation Studio via SSJS and ran it without needing to go through the Automation Studio UI, add to an automation and run it, etc. It was a two-page thing - you entered the name of the target DE, chose Overwrite/Update from a dropdown, and entered your SQL query in a large text box, and clicked run, which would take you to the next page and display a message saying if the query had run successfully or failed. It was a huge time-saver when you wanted to run a one-off query.

At some point in the last six months I got a 'problem loading page' error. I checked Classic Content and yep - all my microsite data is now gone (presumably as a result of the deprecation of Classic Content).

Does anyone know if it has been archived somewhere? I checked CloudPages and it hasn't been moved to there. Anyone have experience recovering old My Microsites data? I'd love to recover it so I can try to recreate it in CloudPages.

Answer (score 3):

There is a quite comprehensive explanation of Classic Content (incl. Microsites) retirement in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392829&type=1). The retirement has been communicated by Salesforce on multiple occasions in context of a.o. release notes. Let me quote:

> Email Studio Classic Web Tools will be retired over several phases.
>
> August 2021 - The ability to create new Microsites and Landing Pages
> will be retired.
>
> June 2022 - Microsites and Landing Pages applications
> will be retired.  All existing Microsites and Landing Pages will be
> unpublished and will no longer be accessible.

You can try reaching out to support, and see if they can recover the code within your old microsite, so you can place it in a cloud page.There is a [good guide here](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/08/09/securing-marketing-cloud-apps-hosted-on-cloudpages/) on how to ensure it can only be accessed by logged in users.